# pythonのインストール時にエラーが出る: MSIMG32.dllはWindows上では実行できないか、エラーを含んでいます

Tags: python, windows-10

Windows 10 64bitです。

pythonのホームページのpython3.8.2のダウンロードページにいって下のファイルから「Windows x86-64実行可能インストーラー」をダウンロードして実行したところ、次のエラーが出ました。

```
C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dllはWindows上では実行できないか、エラーを含んでいます。
元のインストールメディアを使用して再インストールするか、
システム管理者またはソフトウェアの製造元に問い合わせてください。エラー状態 0xc0000020。
```

「実行した時に」というのは、グーグルクロームでインストールした時に画面下にインストールされたものが出てきたのでそれを左クリックしたらこのようなエラーが起きました。

「Windows x86実行可能インストーラー」でも試してみましたが同じエラーが起きました。

エラー状態`0xc0000020`を調べてみたところマカフィーが関係していると聞いてアンインストールしました。
しかし、やり直しても同じエラー状態になります。どうしたらいいでしょうか？

Comment: 当てはまるか分かりませんが、こんな記事があります。応用できるかも。[【Windows】エラー状態0xc0000020(正しくないイメージ)の解決策](https://mell0w-5phere.net/jaded5phere/2017/11/27/windows-error0xc0000020/), [正しくないイメージ「0xc0000020」のエラーが発生し、ScanSnap関連のソフトウェアが動作しません。](https://faq.pfu.jp/faq/show/2141?category_id=118&site_domain=scansnap)

Comment: こちらが類似現象ですが未解決。[.DLL error \[C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll\]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dll-error-cwindowssystem32msimg32dll/9d78dbc4-f720-40f5-b866-d36d0c5569be) こちらはエラーコード違いですが解決済。[SOLVED! "Bad Image" error when opening any software. MSIMG32.dll 0xc000012f](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/solved-bad-image-error-when-opening-any-software/caa9357d-e859-4201-aae6-e6b22afb0c1b) で解決手順のヘルプ。[Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/)

Comment: 教えてくださった　［SOLVED! "Bad Image" error when opening any software. MSIMG32.dll 0xc000012f］　このurlのとおり「Windows 10の回復オプション」を実行して「Windows 10メディア作成ツール」をインストールすると治りました！ありがとうございました！！

Answer (score 1):

コメントに紹介した記事で解決したようなのでまとめてみます。

おそらく最初に紹介したこれらの記事のような症状が発生しているのでしょう。
[【Windows】エラー状態0xc0000020(正しくないイメージ)の解決策](https://mell0w-5phere.net/jaded5phere/2017/11/27/windows-error0xc0000020/)
[正しくないイメージ「0xc0000020」のエラーが発生し、ScanSnap関連のソフトウェアが動作しません。](https://faq.pfu.jp/faq/show/2141?category_id=118&site_domain=scansnap)

その場合、発生した時点でマカフィーによって`C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll`が検疫?されて書き換えられていると思われます。
そのため、Pythonのアンインストール/再インストールや、マカフィーのアンインストールを行っても状況に変化が無かったのでしょう。

該当のファイルはWindowsの一部なので、以下の記事で紹介している[Recovery options in Windows 10](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options)の作業が必要になります。
[.DLL error [C:\Windows\SYSTEM32\MSIMG32.dll]](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/dll-error-cwindowssystem32msimg32dll/9d78dbc4-f720-40f5-b866-d36d0c5569be)
[SOLVED! "Bad Image" error when opening any software. MSIMG32.dll 0xc000012f](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/forum/all/solved-bad-image-error-when-opening-any-software/caa9357d-e859-4201-aae6-e6b22afb0c1b)

日本語の記事はこちら。
[Windows 10 の回復オプション](https://support.microsoft.com/ja-jp/help/12415/windows-10-recovery-options)

コメントに書かれた結果状況によると、**「インストール メディアを使用して PC を復元する」** の作業によって解決できたものと思われます。

それ以外でも、以下の選択肢あたりならば回復できた可能性がありますね。
発生時までの準備状況によって選択可能かどうか分かれますし、どれを選ぶかで、その後に再インストールを必要とするソフトの数も変わるでしょう。

- システムの復元ポイントから復元する
- 回復ドライブを使用して、PC を復元または回復する
- PC を初期状態に戻す

究極はWindows自身を再インストールでしょうか。

- インストール メディアを使用して Windows 10 を再インストールする

時間と心に余裕があれば、マカフィーに対してこんな誤認識の事例があったと報告しておくのも良いと思われます。